# Join two SQL tables but don't multiply rows

Tags: sql-server, select, join

Now i really tryed to find anything in Google since 3 hours.
I've two SQL tables which i want to join with each other.

`Table_LN` is a user table which countains a unique EMail attribute

`Table_AD` is a table with the Active Directory EMail attribute and the User Principle Name (My problem, the EMail address is not equal UPN and also not unique)

My goal is to expand the rows in `Table_LN` with the UPN from `Table_AD`. If there're more then one rows in `Table_AD` with the same EMail address it should take the first one which it will be found. Also i need a filter for countries.

What i tryed is the following code:

```
SELECT 
    [FirstName], 
    [LastName], 
    [EMailAddress],
    [UPN],
    [OfficeCountry]
FROM [Table_LN]
RIGHT JOIN [Table_AD] ON  [Table_LN].[EMailAddress] = [Table_AD].[EMail]
WHERE 
    OfficeCountry = 'Malaysia'
```

My problem is now, that this statment creates me more rows, for each additional EMail address. That means it mulitplies my users in the directory.

Can yomebody help me or do somebody know a topic where somebody ask for this?

Thank you

Comment: Remove `RIGHT` before your JOIN ?

Comment: What Candidate Key is being used to select rows in the Outer Table? in the Inner Table? Unless you are performing a 1 to 0-or-1 match you will always be increasing your row set size.

Comment: What result would you like to have? Return only one specific email, concatenate them into one column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get a smaller table to join into. I like using CTEs. A subquery, temp table, etc would work fine too.

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [UPN],
         [Email],
         [RNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Email] ORDER BY [<PK Field>])
  FROM [Table_AD]
)
SELECT 
    [FirstName], 
    [LastName], 
    [EMailAddress],
    [UPN],
    [OfficeCountry]
FROM [Table_LN]
LEFT JOIN [cte] 
  ON  [cte].[EMail] = [Table_LN].[EMailAddress]
  AND [cte].[RNum] = 1
WHERE 
    OfficeCountry = 'Malaysia'
```

Fiddle with the ORDER BY in the ROW_NUMBER function to change which row is first. Your table's primary key will likely give you the first entry in the table.

Comment: Thats nice! It works exactly how i want! Thank you very much! Now i can go home! ;)